# Is it possible (if so, how) to use jQuery's appendTo with $.Views?

Tags: javascript, jquery, view, javascriptmvc

Here are two ways I have tried and failed:

```
//fails
$( $.Views('//home/home.ejs', {data:data}) ).appendTo('#home');

//fails
$( '//home/home.ejs', {data:data} ).appendTo('#home');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. It should have been $.View and not $.Views. But the second way still won't work.

```
//works
$( $.View('//home/home.ejs', {data:data}) ).appendTo('#home');

//fails
$( '//home/home.ejs', {data:data} ).appendTo('#home');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with $.Views but, try this:

```
$( $.Views('//home/home.ejs', {data:data}) ).appendTo($('#home'));
```

or this:

```
$( '//home/home.ejs', {data:data} ).appendTo($('#home'));
```

when you are calling appendTo, you have to pass a jQuery Selector as the parameter, not only the selector string...

Comment: Seems like it doesn't really care if I pass the string or a $ selector. But thanks though, you made me to go back and check the code again and I found that it should have been $.View and not $.Views

Answer (score 0):

JavascriptMVC overrides some of jQuery's base methods. One of them is .html, allowing to specify a path to a view instead of the inner html:

```
$("#home").html('//home/home.ejs', {data:data});
```

Now, if you want to append, the .append method is overridden with the same functionality:

```
$("#home").append('//home/home.ejs', {data:data});
```

JSMVC Documentation: http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!jQuery.fn.append

Comment: There's a difference between append and appendTo.

Comment: As far as I know is that the difference between append and appendTo is that the matched set of elements, and the given parameter role is switched. Append uses a jQuery selection of what to insert to an element given be parameter, while appendTo the jQuery selection is what to append, and the parameter the container to append it to. In this examples the roles are switched. According to jQuery docs, that is the only difference. Do you have an extended version of appendTo that doesn't allow you to use the append instead of the appendTo method?

Comment: eg. $("I am content.").appendTo('#home').hide().fadeIn(1000); <= this appends the content and hides the content and then fades it in. If you were to use append, it would hide the whole #home and fade that in.